# Building CyanogenMod from source: make: no rule to make target *.so, needed by *.so

Tags: android, c, makefile

I am building AOSP form source, and have made a few modifications to vendor files that are, apparently, not liked by Make. Here is the error I am getting, which involves one of my shiny new files:

make: *** No rule to make target `vendor/lge/g4stylus-common/proprietary/lib/hw/camera/camera.msm8916.so', needed by`/home/brady/android/system/out/target/product/h631/system/lib/hw/camera.msm8916.so'.  Stop.

How can I resolve this error?

Here is my vendor/lge/g4stylus-common/Android.mk, with an attempted fix:

```html
# Copyright (C) 2015 The CyanogenMod Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# This file is generated by device/lge/g4stylus-common/setup-makefiles.sh

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

ifneq ($(filter h631 ms631,$(TARGET_DEVICE)),)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := com.qualcomm.location
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/priv-app/com.qualcomm.location/com.qualcomm.location.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := qcrilmsgtunnel
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/app/qcrilmsgtunnel/qcrilmsgtunnel.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := camera.msm8916
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/lib/hw/camera/camera.msm8916.so
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := shutdownlistener
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/app/shutdownlistener/shutdownlistener.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := TimeService
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/app/TimeService/TimeService.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := qcnvitems
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/framework/qcnvitems.jar
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := qcrilhook
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/framework/qcrilhook.jar
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtime_genoff
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := lge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/vendor/lib/libtime_genoff.so
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_VENDOR_SHARED_LIBRARIES)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I need to do some more troubleshooting before asking for help in the future. Actually didn't have to do with Android.mk at all. I simply referenced the wrong path in the Blobs Mk file.